# CSS page-break properties

Tags: css, less, page-break

I am trying to use CSS page-break properties to avoid a page break after the title span. The html is as follows:

```
<div  class="cnx-eoc free-response">
  <div class="title">
    <span>Review Questions</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS rules I declared are below:

```
div.cnx-eoc.free-response > div.title { 
  page-break-inside: avoid; 
  page-break-after: avoid;
}
```

This solution should work, however I do not get the expected results. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is only limited to being used in Opera. Check browser support http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp

Comment: @Cam `page-break-after` is supported by all. Check here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Comment: I was talking about page-break-inside

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you are trying to use it on `span`. However, page-break-after CSS property applies to block-level elements. Reference: [page-break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after).

Comment: targeting the block level element produces the same result